# why CSCore equalizer SampleFilters[9] (16Khz) does not affect at all in C#

Tags: c#, equalizer, cscore

I recently found that if I want to add equalizer to my application I can use CSCore library! I tested it and it's good! but the problem is that 16Khz equalizer Band (Treble) does not have any effect at all!!
What's wrong what should I do?
I even tried real high numbers! but no effects. :(

```
_equalizer.SampleFilters[9].AverageGainDB = 35.5;
```

Other channels works well (0-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's wrong! I've got the solution :)
the problem was from the Equalizer Sample Source Code I've downloaded from CScore Codeplex Page

```
var source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(ofn.FileName)
                .Loop()
                .ChangeSampleRate(32000)
                .AppendSource(Equalizer.Create10BandEqualizer, out _equalizer)
                .ToWaveSource();
```

I commented the ".ChangeSampleRate" Part and it has been solved!

I changed it to:

```
source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(ofn.FileName)
                .Loop()
                .ChangeSampleRate(44100)
                .AppendSource(Equalizer.Create10BandEqualizer, out _equalizer)
                .ToWaveSource();
```